# PHP opendir/get_files not working after server change

Tags: php

After I moved to one.com I transferred my files and opened the website with the result that I got an error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in /customers/b/8/a/kayblaschke.de/httpd.www/overview.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /customers/b/8/a/kayblaschke.de/httpd.www/overview.php on line 41
```

I havent changed anything from the old server (different host) so i assumed it should work identically which it doesnt. This is the script to read a directory and displaying the image as well as a discription. Whats wrong here? **Thanks a lot!**

```
<?


function get_files($cat1_images_dir,$cat1_exts = array('jpg')) {
    $cat1_files = array();
    if($cat1_handle = opendir($cat1_images_dir)) {
        while(false !== ($cat1_file = readdir($cat1_handle))) {
            $cat1_extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($cat1_file));
            if($cat1_extension && in_array($cat1_extension,$cat1_exts)) {
                $cat1_files[] = $cat1_file;
            }
        }
        closedir($cat1_handle);
    }
    return $cat1_files;
}
function get_file_extension($cat1_file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($cat1_file_name,'.'),1);
}


$cat1_images_dir = 'images_cat1';

echo '
<div class="abstandheader"></div>
<div class="cat" id="cat"> <font class="text"><a href="#" onlick="$(\'#left\').ScrollTo(); return false;">FASHION</a></font></div>
<div class= "gal"> 
<ul class="img-list">
';


$cat1_image_files = get_files($cat1_images_dir);
krsort($cat1_image_files);
// shuffle($cat1_image_files);
if(count($cat1_image_files)) {
    $cat1_index = 0;
    foreach($cat1_image_files as $cat1_index=>$cat1_file) {
        $cat1_index++;
        
        echo '';
        if($cat1_index % $cat1_images_per_row == 0) { 
        
        
                $cat1_file_woext = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $cat1_file);
        
        
            $cat1_file_woext = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $cat1_file);
        
        
        $beschreibung_1 = ''.$cat1_images_dir.$cat1_file_woext.'.txt';
            
        if(file_exists($beschreibung_1)) 

            {
        
$caption = fopen($beschreibung_1, 'r');
        $caption_display = fread($caption, filesize($beschreibung_1));
fclose($caption);


 echo '
  <a href="#" class="img" alt="',$name,'" onclick="$(\'div.container\').hide().load(\'image.php?imageid=',$cat1_images_dir.$cat1_file_woext,'\').fadeIn(1500);return false;" ><li><img src="',$cat1_images_dir.$cat1_file,'" / height="150px"> <span class="text-content"><span><font>'.$caption_display.'</font></span></span></li></a>'; 
            } 

        else

            { 
        
 echo '
  <a href="#" class="img" alt="',$name,'" onclick="$(\'div.container\').hide().load(\'image.php?imageid=',$cat1_images_dir.$cat1_file_woext,'\').fadeIn(1500);return false;" ><li><img src="',$cat1_images_dir.$cat1_file,'" / height="150px"> <span class="text-content"></span></li></a>'; 
            } 



        
        echo '
        
            
        
    
        
        
        ';
        
    
        
        
        
         } 
    }
    echo '';
}
else {
    echo '';
}
```

Comment: `if($cat1_index % $cat1_images_per_row == 0) {` -- where is `$cat_1_images_per_row` defined?

Comment: You most likely had a lower PHP version on your previous set-up, only giving you: `Notice: Undefined variable: cat1_images_per_row in /in/c6KSL`, and 
`Warning: Division by zero in /in/c6KSL`. Newer PHP versions won't let you get away with a division by zero - `Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError:`. You need to set (it is currently undefined) `$cat1_images_per_row` so it never equals zero.

Comment: i dont know. i got this script years ago and wondering why it stopped working.

Comment: thanks berend. how do i define it or what do I assign it to?

Comment: defined it to be "1" and now everthing works again! thanks a million - you guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you understand what is happening in your code, and possibly help you to improve it.

The use of the [modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (`%`) in your script allows the rendering of a sub-set of all images (or captions) in your images directory.

Have a look at the following example:

```
<?php
$cat1 = ['img0', 'img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7', 'img8', 'img9', 'img10'];
$cat1_images_per_row = 2;
foreach ($cat1 as $cat1_index => $cat1_file) {
    if ($cat1_index % $cat1_images_per_row == 0) {
        echo $cat1_file;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
img0img2img4img6img8img10 // setting $cat1_images_per_row = 2; only shows the images/captions with an even index in array `$cat1`.
```

You can see the effect of changing the setting of `$cat1_images_per_row = ...;` in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/jodU1)